# How to add submodules from .repos file

Tags: git

Given a `.repos` file such as the following

```
repositories:
  rmf/rmf_battery:
    type: git
    url: https://github.com/open-rmf/rmf_battery.git
    version: main
  rmf/rmf_internal_msgs:
    type: git
    url: https://github.com/open-rmf/rmf_internal_msgs.git
    version: main
```

that is meant to be cloned with

```
vcs import src < rmf.repos
```

How can I easily add all the repos listed in the `.repos` file as submodules of my current repo?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `--recursive` option

```
vcs import src < rmf.repos --recursive
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the naive approach would be to clone the repos as usual with

```
vcs import src < rmf.repos
```

and then use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10607225/3177701) to loop through the cloned repos and add them to `.gitmodules`.