# Backup using GIT - add, commit and push everything including other GIT repositories

Tags: bash, git, version-control, backup, git-submodules

I want to build a backup system. I have a server (an old pc) and I boot it up via magic packets. For this purpose, I've written a batch Script doing this. On the server is a git server running with a couple of repositories. I can easily push to it.

### But here's the problem:

My project folder contains itself a couple of git repositories. If I now add all files with `git add .`  an Error is thrown, that I should add the submodules. This is the post talking about it [Automatically Add All Submodules to a Repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606101/automatically-add-all-submodules-to-a-repo). I've modified the shell script, to work with spaces, and to automatically commit and push everything while executing.

```bash
cd "D:\Projekts"

find . -type d | while read x ; do
    if [ -d "${x}/.git" ] ; then
        cd "${x}"
        origin="$(git config --get remote.origin.url)"
        cd - 1>/dev/null
    echo ""
    echo git submodule add "${origin}" "${x}"
        git submodule add "${origin}" "${x}"
    fi
done

echo "done adding all submodules"

git add .
git commit -am "new backup"
git push
echo "done pushing"
```

And this doesn't throw an error so far. But still the folders containing all those repositories are empty, if I clone the repository.

*sidenote: I add the remote to the backup repository like this: `$ git remote add --mirror=fetch origin git@<ip>:backup.git`*

Thanks in advance for your time,
Hellow2 :)